# Phone stuck in bootloop even after flashing stock ROM

Tags: boot-loop, mediatek

I currently have a phone named Symphony W17 (MT6572). I had flashed stock ROM using SP Flash Tool, but it's stuck in the boot loop. I tried clearing data and Dalvik cache from recovery but no luck.

```
fastboot getvar all
(bootloader)    partition-size:userdata: 32000000
(bootloader)    partition-type:userdata: ext4
(bootloader)    partition-size:cache: 17800000
(bootloader)    partition-type:cache: ext4
(bootloader)    partition-size:system: 28a00000
(bootloader)    partition-type:system: ext4
(bootloader)    partition-size:expdb: a00000
(bootloader)    partition-type:expdb: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:logo: 300000
(bootloader)    partition-type:logo: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:misc: 80000
(bootloader)    partition-type:misc: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:sec_ro: 40000
(bootloader)    partition-type:sec_ro: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:recovery: 600000
(bootloader)    partition-type:recovery: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:boot: 600000
(bootloader)    partition-type:boot: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:uboot: 60000
(bootloader)    partition-type:uboot: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:seccfg: 20000
(bootloader)    partition-type:seccfg: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:protect_s: a00000
(bootloader)    partition-type:protect_s: ext4
(bootloader)    partition-size:protect_f: a00000
(bootloader)    partition-type:protect_f: ext4
(bootloader)    partition-size:nvram: 500000
(bootloader)    partition-type:nvram: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:pro_info: 300000
(bootloader)    partition-type:pro_info: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:ebr1: 80000
(bootloader)    partition-type:ebr1: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:mbr: 80000
(bootloader)    partition-type:mbr: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:preloader: c00000
(bootloader)    partition-type:preloader: raw data
(bootloader)    kernel: lk
(bootloader)    product: UP11_ID_SYMPHONY_W17
(bootloader)    version: 0.5
all: Done!!
finished. total time: 0.078s

...................................................................
```

Firmware I flashed - https://www.mediafire.com/file/8csalmwtcxf0nme/Symphony_W17_V01.5_UP11.zip

SP flash tool version - 5.1516

Scatter - https://drive.google.com/file/d/12jhrdeM8bKjPU5Ej0KZVfEK4ZBg5DVzq/view?usp=sharing

`MT6572_Android_scatter.txt`

```
############################################################################################################
#
#  General Setting
#
############################################################################################################
- general: MTK_PLATFORM_CFG
  info:
    - config_version: V1.1.1
      platform: MT6572
      project: mtk_android
      storage: EMMC
      boot_channel: MSDC_0
      block_size: 0x20000
############################################################################################################
#
#  Layout Setting
#
############################################################################################################
- partition_index: SYS0
  partition_name: PRELOADER
  file_name: preloader.bin
  is_download: true
  type: SV5_BL_BIN
  linear_start_addr: 0x0
  physical_start_addr: 0x0
  partition_size: 0xC00000
  region: EMMC_BOOT_1
  storage: HW_STORAGE_EMMC
  boundary_check: true
  is_reserved: false
  operation_type: BOOTLOADER
  reserve: 0x00

- partition_index: SYS1
  partition_name: MBR
  file_name: MBR.bin
  is_download: true
  type: NORMAL_ROM
  linear_start_addr: 0xC00000
  physical_start_addr: 0x0
  partition_size: 0x80000
  region: EMMC_USER
  storage: HW_STORAGE_EMMC
  boundary_check: true
  is_reserved: false
  operation_type: UPDATE
  reserve: 0x00

- partition_index: SYS2
  partition_name: EBR1
  file_name: EBR1.bin
  is_download: true
  type: NORMAL_ROM
  linear_start_addr: 0xC80000
  physical_start_addr: 0x0
  partition_size: 0x80000
  region: EMMC_USER
  storage: HW_STORAGE_EMMC
  boundary_check: true
  is_reserved: false
  operation_type: UPDATE
  reserve: 0x00

- partition_index: SYS3
  partition_name: PRO_INFO
  file_name: NONE
  is_download: false
  type: NONE
  linear_start_addr: 0xD00000
  physical_start_addr: 0x0
  partition_size: 0x300000
  region: EMMC_USER
  storage: HW_STORAGE_EMMC
  boundary_check: true
  is_reserved: false
  operation_type: PROTECTED
  reserve: 0x00

- partition_index: SYS4
  partition_name: NVRAM
  file_name: nvram.bin
  is_download: true
  type: NORMAL_ROM
  linear_start_addr: 0x1000000
  physical_start_addr: 0x0
  partition_size: 0x500000
  region: EMMC_USER
  storage: HW_STORAGE_EMMC
  boundary_check: true
  is_reserved: false
  operation_type: UPDATE
  reserve: 0x00

- partition_index: SYS5
  partition_name: PROTECT_F
  file_name: protect_f.bin
  is_download: true
  type: NORMAL_ROM
  linear_start_addr: 0x1500000
  physical_start_addr: 0x0
  partition_size: 0xA00000
  region: EMMC_USER
  storage: HW_STORAGE_EMMC
  boundary_check: true
  is_reserved: false
  operation_type: UPDATE
  reserve: 0x00

- partition_index: SYS6
  partition_name: PROTECT_S
  file_name: protect_s.bin
  is_download: true
  type: NORMAL_ROM
  linear_start_addr: 0x1F00000
  physical_start_addr: 0x0
  partition_size: 0xA00000
  region: EMMC_USER
  storage: HW_STORAGE_EMMC
  boundary_check: true
  is_reserved: false
  operation_type: UPDATE
  reserve: 0x00

- partition_index: SYS7
  partition_name: SECCFG
  file_name: NONE
  is_download: false
  type: NONE
  linear_start_addr: 0x2900000
  physical_start_addr: 0x0
  partition_size: 0x20000
  region: EMMC_USER
  storage: HW_STORAGE_EMMC
  boundary_check: true
  is_reserved: false
  operation_type: INVISIBLE
  reserve: 0x00

- partition_index: SYS8
  partition_name: UBOOT
  file_name: uboot.bin
  is_download: true
  type: NORMAL_ROM
  linear_start_addr: 0x2920000
  physical_start_addr: 0x0
  partition_size: 0x60000
  region: EMMC_USER
  storage: HW_STORAGE_EMMC
  boundary_check: true
  is_reserved: false
  operation_type: UPDATE
  reserve: 0x00

- partition_index: SYS9
  partition_name: BOOTIMG
  file_name: bootimg.bin
  is_download: true
  type: NORMAL_ROM
  linear_start_addr: 0x2980000
  physical_start_addr: 0x0
  partition_size: 0x600000
  region: EMMC_USER
  storage: HW_STORAGE_EMMC
  boundary_check: true
  is_reserved: false
  operation_type: UPDATE
  reserve: 0x00

- partition_index: SYS10
  partition_name: RECOVERY
  file_name: recovery.bin
  is_download: true
  type: NORMAL_ROM
  linear_start_addr: 0x2F80000
  physical_start_addr: 0x0
  partition_size: 0x600000
  region: EMMC_USER
  storage: HW_STORAGE_EMMC
  boundary_check: true
  is_reserved: false
  operation_type: UPDATE
  reserve: 0x00

- partition_index: SYS11
  partition_name: SEC_RO
  file_name: secro.bin
  is_download: true
  type: NORMAL_ROM
  linear_start_addr: 0x3580000
  physical_start_addr: 0x0
  partition_size: 0x40000
  region: EMMC_USER
  storage: HW_STORAGE_EMMC
  boundary_check: true
  is_reserved: false
  operation_type: UPDATE
  reserve: 0x00

- partition_index: SYS12
  partition_name: MISC
  file_name: misc.bin
  is_download: true
  type: NORMAL_ROM
  linear_start_addr: 0x35C0000
  physical_start_addr: 0x0
  partition_size: 0x80000
  region: EMMC_USER
  storage: HW_STORAGE_EMMC
  boundary_check: true
  is_reserved: false
  operation_type: UPDATE
  reserve: 0x00

- partition_index: SYS13
  partition_name: LOGO
  file_name: logo.bin
  is_download: true
  type: NORMAL_ROM
  linear_start_addr: 0x3640000
  physical_start_addr: 0x0
  partition_size: 0x300000
  region: EMMC_USER
  storage: HW_STORAGE_EMMC
  boundary_check: true
  is_reserved: false
  operation_type: UPDATE
  reserve: 0x00

- partition_index: SYS14
  partition_name: EXPDB
  file_name: NONE
  is_download: false
  type: NONE
  linear_start_addr: 0x3940000
  physical_start_addr: 0x0
  partition_size: 0xA00000
  region: EMMC_USER
  storage: HW_STORAGE_EMMC
  boundary_check: true
  is_reserved: false
  operation_type: INVISIBLE
  reserve: 0x00

- partition_index: SYS15
  partition_name: ANDROID
  file_name: system.bin
  is_download: true
  type: YAFFS_IMG
  linear_start_addr: 0x4340000
  physical_start_addr: 0x0
  partition_size: 0x28A00000
  region: EMMC_USER
  storage: HW_STORAGE_EMMC
  boundary_check: true
  is_reserved: false
  operation_type: UPDATE
  reserve: 0x00

- partition_index: SYS16
  partition_name: CACHE
  file_name: cache.bin
  is_download: true
  type: YAFFS_IMG
  linear_start_addr: 0x2CD40000
  physical_start_addr: 0x0
  partition_size: 0x17800000
  region: EMMC_USER
  storage: HW_STORAGE_EMMC
  boundary_check: true
  is_reserved: false
  operation_type: UPDATE
  reserve: 0x00

- partition_index: SYS17
  partition_name: USRDATA
  file_name: userdata.bin
  is_download: true
  type: YAFFS_IMG
  linear_start_addr: 0x44540000
  physical_start_addr: 0x0
  partition_size: 0x52C00000
  region: EMMC_USER
  storage: HW_STORAGE_EMMC
  boundary_check: true
  is_reserved: false
  operation_type: UPDATE
  reserve: 0x00

- partition_index: SYS18
  partition_name: FAT
  file_name: fat.bin
  is_download: true
  type: YAFFS_IMG
  linear_start_addr: 0x97140000
  physical_start_addr: 0x0
  partition_size: 0x4E5E0000
  region: EMMC_USER
  storage: HW_STORAGE_EMMC
  boundary_check: true
  is_reserved: false
  operation_type: UPDATE
  reserve: 0x00

- partition_index: SYS19
  partition_name: BMTPOOL
  file_name: NONE
  is_download: false
  type: NONE
  linear_start_addr: 0xFFFF00A8
  physical_start_addr: 0x0
  partition_size: 0x1500000
  region: EMMC_USER
  storage: HW_STORAGE_EMMC
  boundary_check: false
  is_reserved: true
  operation_type: RESERVED
  reserve: 0x00
```

Comment: you forgot to flash stock recovery (or disable dm-verity in case wanna keep TWRP)

Comment: I flashed stock recovery and firmware using sp flash tool but im stuck in bootloop. What should i do now ? Do you have telegram , discord or anything ? Please help me!!

Comment: Don't worry you will get help here. But please be descriptive - update your question with output of *'fastboot getvar all'* (with IMEI + Serialno censored) and post link to stock ROM or scatter file used, and also partitions list selected for flashing, maybe there is a discrepancy

Comment: I colud not write not write it here. So I have written it on pastebin. Here is the link of the paste - https://pastebin.com/x6qsnTWQ   ...... Please help me!

Comment: there is discrepancy userdata partition 1.3 GB or 800 MB which partitions did you flash and what download mode selected?

Comment: I selected format all + download mode on sp flash tool. Userdata partiton was 1.3gb

Comment: you formatted whole eMMC so maybe some partitions got lost. you can try to fix with MTK tools

Comment: can you guide me ? please

Comment: [This](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/lenovo-tab-7-essential-tb-7304f-hard-bricked.3934944/page-4#post-81707215) partitions probably got lost. [This](https://androidmtk.com/use-sn-write-tool) can partially restore some data, but I cannot guide you I never did. XDA is a better place to have such conversations, Android Enthusiasts is Q&A site only (1 Question, 1 Solution)

Comment: some notes regarding SP Flash Tool https://android.stackexchange.com/q/232584 https://android.stackexchange.com/q/209989 https://android.stackexchange.com/q/212931

Comment: Hey. I flashed another rom and it booted but when i try to erase storage from recovery it says unable to mount /data also i cannot install any apps. its saying that i dont have enough storage. here is link of scatter and firmware - Scatter - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V4Ly5h8xQnIezIiKK6KrCbtROH90FHVX/view?usp=sharing
Firmware - https://androidfilehost.com/?fid=673956719939828710 . please help

Comment: i think its stuck in bootloop again. tried flashing again with that rom but still same

Comment: something is different this time. did you flash custom recovery?

Comment: i did nothing my phones battery died so i charged it and when i tried to start it its stuck in the starting logo

Comment: someone told me to repartition my phone's internal storage. do you know how to do it?

Comment: you did already with SP Flash Tool *Format all*, that's why your `persist` and `nvram` partitions are gone - bad advise. Let us continue discussion on [xda](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/my-phone-is-stuck-in-bootloop-even-after-flashing-with-stock-firmware.4387787)

Comment: you are my only hope. none other replies to my questions